# composer require specific version

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I need to use jenssegers/blade package in environments with php 5.6 so I need to use illuminate 5.1 (exactly this version). In vendors/jenssegers/blade/composer.json it requires

```
"require": {
    "illuminate/view": "^5.1"
},
```

Executing composer update it downloads latest version of illuminate (5.6.17) that requires php 7+.

Laravel 5.1 works with php >= 5.5.9 and should be the same for illuminate 5.1.

I would like to force the download of illuminate 5.1 so I deleted vendors/lluminate directory and edited vendors/jenssegers/blade/composer.json removing '^' before version:

```
"require": {
    "illuminate/view": "5.1"
}
```

But composer update keep downloading:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 6 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
- Installing illuminate/contracts (v5.6.17): Loading from cache
- Installing illuminate/support (v5.6.17): Loading from cache
- Installing illuminate/filesystem (v5.6.17): Loading from cache
- Installing illuminate/container (v5.6.17): Loading from cache
- Installing illuminate/events (v5.6.17): Loading from cache
- Installing illuminate/view (v5.6.17): Loading from cache
```

Comment: use composer install instead?

Comment: Try: edit `vendor/laravel/framework/composer.json` from `"illuminate/view": "self.version"` to `"illuminate/view": "^5.1"`

Comment: Using composer install I get 5.6.17 (like composer update). I don't have vendor/laravel. I'm using jessengers/blade because I need only blade without  laravel.

Comment: @SandOfVega never edit stuff in `vendor`. Never.

Comment: I know @NicoHaase. But there is no other way in this situation. :|

Comment: Why not? Shouldn't adding the exact required versions to the **own** `composer.json` fix all problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a installation for PHP 5.6 you should add this to your `composer.json`:

```
"config": {
    "platform": {
        "php": "5.6"
    }
},
```

https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform

If you need to lock to specified version of package, you may also add constraint to your `composer.json`, but configuring PHP version is usually a better idea.

```
"require": {
    "illuminate/view": "5.1.*"
},
```

Comment: Side note: there is no v5.1 of the given package

Comment: @NicoHaase There is a [5.1.41](https://packagist.org/packages/illuminate/view#v5.1.41) which makes this constraint installable.

Comment: But the constraint "5.1" should not install "5.1.41", that's why you are requiring for v 5.1